# Change ratio in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, latex, knitr

I am using `knitr`, `ggplot`. I want a plot like this: 
[image: Plot wider] 
to be shown better. But I still get something like this: 
[image: narrow plot]

```
\begin{landscape}
<< mygrah2>>=
require(ggplot2)
 ggplot(T2,aes(x=age,y=value,fill=Position))
 +geom_boxplot()+ggtitle("Distribuition of frequencies per age in 3
 collected positions.\n N=1000,K=10,T=2")+theme(legend.position="bottom")
@ 
\end{landscape}
```

I already try options `out.width`, `fig.width` but not working.

Edit:

I am sure that I'm using knitr. I did an example below. As @Thierry sad the solution is use a fig.height AND fig.width together. Thanks very much.

```
\documentclass[letterpaper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage{color}

 \usepackage{placeins}
 \usepackage{graphicx}

 \usepackage{booktabs}

 \usepackage{lscape}
 \usepackage{fullpage}
 \usepackage{pdflscape}


\begin{document}

<<readdata>>=
data(mtcars)
mtcars$gear <- factor(mtcars$gear,levels=c(3,4,5),
  labels=c("3gears","4gears","5gears"))
mtcars$cyl <- factor(mtcars$cyl,levels=c(4,6,8),
  labels=c("4cyl","6cyl","8cyl")) 

require(ggplot2)
@ 

\begin{landscape}
<<migraph>>=
#normal plot
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=gear,y=mpg,fill=gear))+geom_boxplot()
@ 


<<migraph2,fig.width=10>>=
# weird 
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=gear,y=mpg,fill=gear))+geom_boxplot() 
@ 

<<migraph3,fig.height=2,fig.width=10>>= 
# It is what I looking for
 ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=gear,y=mpg,fill=gear))+geom_boxplot()
@ 


<<migraph4,out.height="2in",out.width="10in">>=
# weird 
ggplot(mtcars,aes(x=gear,y=mpg,fill=gear))+geom_boxplot()
@ 

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: setting fig.width and fit.height should work. If not, then post a reproducible example

Comment: [How to make a great R reproducible example?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269)

Comment: Are you sure your are using knitr? You can check whether you are not using Sweave -> Tools -> Global Options -> Sewave -> Weave Rnw files using -> check whether you have there knitr or Sweave? You should change to knitr if your want to use knitr chunks options

Answer (score 1):

The behavior of `fig.width` and `out.width` are different.  `fig.width` controls the size of the actual figure, say 5 inches.  The `out.width` option controls how the graphic is displayed in the document.  As such, if you have `fig.width = 5` and `out.width = 0.5\\textwidth` then a figure that is five inches wide is created, and in LaTeX, the graphic is included via `\includegraphics[width = 0.5\textwidth]`  Note that the backslash needs to be escaped when defining the value for `out.width`.

By default, the chuck options are:

- `fig.width = 7`
- `fig.height = 7`
- `out.width = NULL`
- `out.height = NULL`

The `out.*` options defaults are set by output type.  See the documentation for [chunk options](https://yihui.name/knitr/options/#plots).

Your `migraph` is a 7x7 figure with `\includegraphics[width=\maxwidth]` where `\maxwidth` is defined [here](https://yihui.name/knitr/demo/framed/)

`migraph2` is a 10x7 figure with the same default output width.

`migraph3` is a 2x10 inch figure with standard output width.

`migraph4` forces a 7x7 inch figure into a 10x2 inch frame, yeah, that's going to look weird.